# SQL Serverでキャラクターとして格納されている16進数の数値を、通常の数値に変換してビット演算したい

Tags: sql, sql-server

カラムの定義が `char(6)` となっているカラムにキャラクター文字列で16進数の数値が入っているのですが、それを通常の数値に変換する方法は無いでしょうか。

`'a','b','0','0','0','0'` というようにデータが入っています。

それを、int型の数値に(上記の場合だと `11206656` というように)変換するのはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

帳票に出力するのにそのカラムの中の数値をビット演算して出力するというようにしたいのですが、従来からあるデータベースなので今更変更は出来なくて、帳票用のデータをDB側で作らなければならなくて困っています。

Comment: このSQLServerのデータへのアクセスは何で行っているのでしょうか？プログラムを作成して、データを読み込めばそこで変換すればいいと思いますが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

バイナリ形式へ変換して数値に変換すればいけるかと

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, CONVERT(VARBINARY, 'ab0000', 2))
```

[CAST および CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
のバイナリ スタイルを参照してください

前ゼロ付加したいのであれば

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, CONVERT(VARBINARY,right('000000'+TRIM('ab000'),6), 2))
```

でいけるかと
ただこれでも不正な文字があるとエラーになるだろうし、事前にデータのサニタイズは必要かもしれませんが

Comment: 対象カラムの値が全て 6 桁になっているという前提であれば問題はないのですが、[Binary styles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#binary-styles) には "The expression must have an **even number of hexadecimal digits**" と記載されていますので、例えば `SELECT CONVERT(int, CONVERT(VARBINARY, 'ab000', 2))` の場合は 5 桁なのでエラーになってしまいます。奇数桁の場合には偶数桁になる様に先頭に `0` を追加する必要があります(`0ab000`)。

Comment: とりあえず回答に追記はしましたが、そもそもchar(6)なのでデータ上は必ず6文字です。空白をトリムした上で前ゼロ付加すべきか後に付加すべきなのか、エラーではじくべきかは判断が付きかねます

Comment: ええと、`char(6)` と宣言した場合、格納可能な最大文字数が6文字ということになりますので、`ab000` を insert した場合(5文字)、select の結果は `ab000` になります。

Comment: charは固定長です（可変長はvarchar）。その場合のselect結果は末尾にスペースが付加されて6文字返されますよ

Comment: [こちら](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d98d01/6) をご覧ください。

Comment: [Len](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)は、指定された文字列式の、末尾の空白を除いた文字数を返します。データ上は(select結果も)末尾に空白があるのです

Comment: なるほど！、大変失礼しました。`DATALENGTH` を使うべきなのですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
カラムに入るデータは「16進以外の文字列を入れたら、そのアプリのバグ」ということで、SQLServer側では対処しないということになりました